How to check if a given instance is still in the application memory?
I have an application made with WPF, C# together with .NET 8.
The application is extremely simple to use, with a screen and two buttons that load two different UserControls.
MainWindow.xaml:
<StackPanel Height="450" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="Screen 1" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="50 10 0 10" Click="Button_Click_1" />
        <Button Content="Screen 2" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="50 10 0 10" Click="Button_Click_2" />
    </WrapPanel>
    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentControl" Width="800" Height="385" />
</StackPanel>

MainWindow.xaml.cs:
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ContentControl.Content = new ScreenOneControl();
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentControl.Content = new ScreenOneControl();
}

private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentControl.Content = new ScreenTwoControl();
}

Inside my ScreenOneWindow.xaml and ScreenTwoWindow.xaml I have the same <Label>, with diferrent messages:
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Label Content="Screen 01" FontSize="30" />
</Grid>

Although the operation of this application seems to be very simple, I would like to find a way to make sure that for each instance that is being assigned to my <ContentControl>, the previous one is being removed from memory.
That said, is there any code that I can insert into my Immediate Window (or anywhere else), so that I can check without there still being instances in memory?
For example, I clicked on the Screen 2 Button, and I would like to make sure that the new ScreenTwoWindow() instance is still taking up space in the application.

What is ScreenOneControl? Why is it a problem to have both controls instantiated? Do you suspect/have memory leaks?

My ScreenOneControl and ScreenTwoControl is a simple UserControl class with any code behind. My problem is that I see my application's memory increasing, along with Objects (Diff) and Heap Size. Because of this, I'm thinking that there might be a memory leak. Since the application's GC is not being shown in the Graph at any time (at least when I implement GC.Collect() in the code).

Related.

Do you need to create a new instance each time? Why not instantiate one of each instance when constructing the form then set the appropriate reference on the button click? Even if you want to clear the contents of the final user control that's generally quite easy to implement without instantiating a new control each time.

Use a memory profiler. This should let you capture snapshots of the memory, and search for any types that are in memory. It should also trigger a full GC before capturing snapshots.
If you suspect a memory leak you can compare snapshots, order objects by retained bytes or object count etc. Or to just search for types to see how many objects are alive. This should let you find suspicious objects fairly quickly.
Note that different profilers may offer different functionality. I have not used the builtin visual studio profiler much, so I'm not sure if it offers all features.
Note that WPF has had some issues with keeping objects alive in unexpected ways. I'm not sure if all these issues have been fixed or not. But it might be to just create your controls once, and just swap them out when needed. That might avoid some potential issues.
